# javax.servlet does not exist

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm using linux for the first time to develop servlet/jsp. When I tried to compile a simple servlet, I got javax.servlet does not exist. What should I do? I know it's a problem with the path but how do I correct it without overwriting values already in the path.

Where should I place the .class servlet? The book I'm reading about servlets is saying one thing, the I find yet other things online. I don't want to mess the settings up. I found and online poster suggesting to create a folder under /usr/share/tomcat6/webapp and move all the .class there and it will work without any further settings. Is this true?

Thank you very much,
Mike

Comment: You must not implement the `Servlet` class, that's from Java EE environments. Make sure you have created a Web Dynamic Project (Eclipse) and you have set the project to be deployed on Tomcat (or another web application server) that already gives you the `Servlet`  class.

Comment: You should look for a decent tutorial on how to create web applications with Java. It's a bit confusing at the start, because you've got to have a certain structure of folders, a web.xml file and so on. As Luiggi Mendoza said, using Eclipse will help you a lot because it automatically creates the needed folders etc. but you should also know what's going on.

Comment: I already sent you the link to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html. And this page has an explanation on the directory layout, which does NOT consist in putting all the .class files under /usr/share/tomcat6/webapp. If you don't read the answers you get, why should we answer? It looks like you don't know at all how Java works, what jar files are and how to configure your classpath. Don't start with servlets. Start with basic stuff.

Comment: We've all been here before!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added servlet-api.jar to your classpath? if not, this jar should be present in your classpath in-order to work with servlets.

Comment: I edited the export line in ~/.bash_profile from    

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin    
export PATH    

to      

PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/tomcat6-servlet-2.5-api-6.0.24.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/tomcat6-jsp-2.1-api-6.0.24.jar:/usr/share/tomcat6/lib/tomcat6-el-2.1-api-6.0.24.jar:$HOME/bin    
export PATH      

restarted the computer but still I get the same error " javax.servlet does not exist"        

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this compilation error,
1. copy the jar file: tomcat\common\lib\servlet-api.jar or tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar
2. paste it to Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\jre\lib\ext

/// your installation path may slightly differ.

Comment: The path is for Windows users only, and this is not really the modern way of doing it. You should probably use Maven instead.